# Returning more than one row with MySQLi

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to make one variable ($order_description) echo 27 rows from my database using the following code:

```
$sql_query1 = "SELECT order_description FROM single_user_orders WHERE username = '". $_SESSION['login_user'] ."'";
$result1 = mysqli_query($dbconfig, $sql_query1);
$row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$count1 = mysqli_num_rows($result1);

if($count1 >= 1) {
    while ($row1 = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {
        $order_description = $row1['order_description'];
    }
}
```

Although this code is working, when I `<?php echo $order_description; ?>` it returns the last row of the SELECT statement and not the 27 rows I should be seeing, where am I going wrong?

Comment: Your 'error' is within the while loop. You are reading all rows but assigning them to the same variable. With this the next one replaces the former one with every run of this loop. This leaves the last row in the variable when the loop finishes.

Comment: use mysql group_concat in query and php explode function in code. look on my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to see all 27 descriptions, you need to either print them within the loop or add them to an array.  When you run a loop and output a single variable only after the loop has ended, it will display the last value assigned.

```
while ($row1 = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {
    $order_description = $row1['order_description'];
    echo $order_description."\n";
}
```

OR

```
while ($row1 = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {
    $descriptions[]=$row1['order_description'];
}
print_r($descriptions);
```

**Note**

@RiggsFolly  rightly noted that you have one extra fetch_array call which gets wasted and hence you will never see the first row. Get rid of that.

Kick the third line of your code

```
$row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Might want to also warn him that the first `$row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1, MYSQLI_ASSOC);` line will loose him the first row

Comment: How would you retrieve the first row too?

Comment: Note my previous comment. Remove the `mysqli_fetch_array()` that you have just after the `mysqli_query()` that is reading the first row and doing nothing with it

Comment: is it correct to mix procedural+object-oriented approach

Comment: Its actually not, but then its PHP, you can get away with a lot :)

Comment: You can get away with it when using the `mysqli` api, not sure about anything else

Comment: i think he mixed it because of `$result1->fetch_assoc() `  and `mysqli_query($dbconfig, $sql_query1)`

Answer (score 1):

use below way with group_concat and read the comments

```
$sql_query1 = "SELECT group_concat(order_description separator ',') as order_description FROM single_user_orders WHERE username = '". $_SESSION['login_user'] ."'" ; // update thie query with group_concat
$result1 = mysqli_query($dbconfig, $sql_query1);
$count1 = mysqli_num_rows($result1);
$order_description = array();
if($count1 >= 1) {
    while ($row1 = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {
        $order_description = explode(',',$row1['order_description']); // explode the string 
    }

}

print_r($order_description);
```